# Surface integrals in Force Fields

Tags: vector-fields, surface-integrals, divergence-operator

So I am given the following question:

On $\mathbb{R}^3\backslash \{\underline{0}\}$ consider the vector field \begin{align*}
    \underline{F}(x,y,z) = (0,\frac{-2yz}{r^4}, \frac{-1}{r^2}+ \frac{2y^2}{r^4}), \text{with } r = \sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}
\end{align*}
and the surface $\mathcal{S}$ given by $x^2+y^2+\frac{1}{4}z^2 = 1$, $z\geq0$.
The surface normal points away from the origin. Evaluate $\iint\limits_{\mathcal{S}} (\underline{F}, \underline{n}) \ d\sigma$.

I am struggling to approach this question since the $0$ vector is not included in the domain. Do I have to make any special considerations that we would not do if we took the whole of $\mathbb{R}^3$? Any help/hints with the initial steps is appreciated.

Comment: Well, $\vec{0}$ **can't** be an element of the domain since the prescription for $F$ would have division by zero there.  But it does mean that certain theorems that require $F$ be continuous/differentiable/whatever on the interior of the surface of integration do not apply here.

Comment: Yes, and I am aware there is some method to make this follow the criteria to use those theorems, but I do not understand how to do that.

Comment: You can always do direct surface integral as the vector field is defined at all points on the surface.